# how to create prev and next buttons in calendar php, javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I wrote a calendar `function cal($current_month,$current_day,$current_year)` which returns an array, `calender_arr("month"=>$m, "day"=>$day,"year"=>"year", "tabular_calendar_data"=>$data)`.

The `$data` is a table with calendar dates, weeks etc. The table has two `<<` and `>>` 'th' (i.e column heading) when pressed they should trigger `prevMonth($calendar_arr["month"],$calendar_arr["day"],$calendar_arr["year"])` and `nextMonth($calendar_arr["month"],$calendar_arr["day"],$calendar_arr["year"])`. These two functions internally call call a function and assign the previous months values to `cal` so it can generate calendar of last month and next month respectively.

The logic is fine but  here is my problem I am unable to call the php `prevMonth()` and `nextMonth()`  at the `onclick()` on the calendar's `<<` and `>>`. Can any body suggest a way of approaching this? I tried jQuery and AJAX but I am not that fluent that's why its not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a tiny bit more specific? example, what is not working when you set the onclick values in your "<<" and ">>" buttons? did you link them properly? <a href="#" onClick="prevMonth();">&lt;&lt;</a> ? Perhaps post your javascript and html code so we can see if it's an issue with your syntax or theory.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is call a PHP function from a Javascript event. It won't work because PHP is run on the server and Javascript is run on the client.

So what is happening is that the onclick event is looking for a Javascript function (which would not be defined) instead of calling your PHP cal function.

What you can do is create a javascript function that makes an AJAX call to the server to retrieve the previous month and next month. Then, you would use the << and >> button call the function you just created and pass in the date you want to retrieve.

Comment: Hi THanks for response. @Rory McCrossan $ben Ashton, the problem is since calendar is returned as a string by my cal function , I am unable to do onclick

Output of cal($m,$d,$y) is an array i.e eg:
$myarr["month"] = 03 ,$myarr["day"] = 06, , $myarr["year"] =2012, $myarr["tabular_calendar_data"] ="<table><tr><th> << </th><th> $m $y </th><th> >></th></tr><tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</td>....<td>31</td></tr></table>". How to add onclickto the <th> <<</th> ?? Since the table is already returned , I tried adding jquery addClass or addJavascript but I could not make it work...

Comment: Thanks for response @ken woo.I know we can use ajax but how to call a function cal() on a php page thru ajax as far as I know we can only call the content of a php page thru ajax but I dont know how to call a function..please advise

Comment: Create another php file, and within that script you can do: 
`$month = $_GET['month'];`
`$year = $_GET['year'];`
and then use those to pass into your cal function and then echo the response. For example: `echo cal($month, $year)`. Then within javascript, you can use the innerHtml function to replace the table with the response